# how am i receiving notification from Firebase even when i remove onMessageReceived()

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am working with FCM to receive push notifications. I am so confused with this I can easily push notification and receive them with my Firebase account but I am not getting its proper flow.

I've used this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and to understand how it works I removed `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {....}`
and I am still getting notification.

I'd like to understand the flow of notification received from Firebase.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that either newer Android versions or newer Firebase post the Android notification automatically for you. If you don't want that then I think you'd override and provide an empty body.

Comment: If you have access to source code of `FirebaseMessagingService` then see the `onMessageReceived()`. It might be posting an Android notification there.

Comment: thanks for the rpl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is in the foreground, the method `onMessageReceived` will be called and notification will not be shown.

If your app is in the background (not running or minimized), the method `onMessageReceived` will not be called and you will get notification directly.

So if your app is in the background, there will be no impact of removing `onMessageReceived` method. You will still get the notifications.

Comment: ohhkkk If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification then if i want to handle them in a bundle , how i'll imlement????

Comment: If you click in the notification, the launcher activity will be opened. You can get the extras in the launcher activity using `getIntent().getExtras()`

Comment: this is my onReceive() ---> if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d("Msg", "Message received ["+remoteMessage+"]");

            // Create Notification
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1410,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new
                    NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Message")
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                    .setGroup("grp")
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Comment: when i fire notification its not making group. it always update my previous notification with new notif.

Comment: Use a different notification id for different notifications. Using a same notification id will replace the old notification for that id.

Comment: its working I applied this code long time = new Date().getTime();
            String tmpStr = String.valueOf(time);
            String last4Str = tmpStr.substring(tmpStr.length() - 5);
            int notificationId = Integer.valueOf(last4Str);            now i can see different notif. on my notif. bar but still i cant Bundled them....

Answer (score 2):

What type of notification you are sending it from your back-end?

If its type of 
`"notification": { }` 
then android system will handle this and responsible to display notification.

If you are using `"data" : { }` then you will get those details in onMessageReceived() callback.

Comment: looks like perfect answer.